# Improve simple SQL select performance

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables with some data ( > 300_000 rows) and this simple query is taking ~1 seconds.
Any idea to make it faster?

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM a 
INNER JOIN b on (a.b_id = b.id)
WHERE b.some_int_column = 2
ORDER BY a.id DESC
LIMIT 0,10
```

Both, a.b_id and b.some_int_column have indexes. Also, a.id and i.id are integer primary keys.

When I try a explain, it says first it is using some_int_column index, with temporary and filesort.

If I do this same query, but ordering by b.id ASC it takes ~0.2 ms instead (I know this is because in such case I'm ordering by first explain row), but I really need to order by a table.

Is there something I am missing?

Comment: Is there a typo in your `ORDER BY`? Is it supposed to be `ORDER BY a.b_id`?

Comment: Is it because MySQL does not have DESC indexes until version 8?

Comment: I'm not understanding. ASC or DESC makes a difference for an index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this query:

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM a INNER JOIN
     b
     ON a.b_id = b.id
WHERE b.some_int_column = 2
ORDER BY a.id DESC
LIMIT 0, 10;
```

The optimal indexes are likely to be `b(some_int_column, id)`, and `a, b_id, id)`.

You might find that this version has better performance with these indexes:

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM a 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM b
              WHERE a.b_id = b.id AND b.some_int_column = 2
             )
ORDER BY a.id DESC
LIMIT 0, 10;
```

For this query, the indexes should be `a(id, b_id)` and `b(id, some_int_column)`.

Comment: Wow, using exists instead of inner join this query takes ~0.3 ms instead of ~800 ms. This is a great improvement, but makes me think something is wrong with MySQL - I thought there should not require tricks to make a query faster, it should be a matter for DB engine optimization.

Comment: Indeed it looks too much better. It seems really wrong that two tables joined (as model, which is pretty common) need to be queried via EXISTS to have a good performance

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM b 
INNER JOIN a on (b.id = a.b_id)
WHERE b.some_int_column = 2
ORDER BY a.id DESC
LIMIT 0,10
```

Try this.  Because your are filtering on a column in table B, not a column in Table A.  This may reduce the volume of data read.  Depending on the sql optimizer it may match up all records in the join and then filter out those =2.  But reversing it, the optimizer may only match up records in table b to a that are = 2 in your where clause.